# How to place an op amp using the input anchor's position?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, opamp

I have a circuit that consists of a few components, and would like to know how can I draw an op amp without knowing the center position of the op amp.

Here is the code I currently have

Note: This is extremely simplified, I have many more components in the drawing.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0, 0) to[R=$R_s$, *-*] ++ (0, -3) coordinate (vp) ++ (0, -3) to[zzD=$v_Z$, *-] ++ (0, 3);
    % How to initialise the op amp on the RHS of the resistor and Zener diode?
    \node[op amp, yscale=-1] (opamp) {};
    \draw (opamp.+) to[short] (vp);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of code.]

As you can see, the op amp initialises at the origin, and `vp` does not go to the RHS of the node between the resistor and diode.

Here is what I would like:

[image: Desired output.]

As you can see, the "center" anchor of the op amp is unknown, so how can I initialise the op amp using the positive input anchor (which is known)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Rmano thanks for reminding me! I was very busy that day haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You draw the wire and then position the op-amp with the appropriate anchor:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0, 0) to[R=$R_s$, *-*] ++ (0, -3) coordinate (vp) ++ (0, -3) to[zzD=$v_Z$, *-] ++ (0, 3);
    % How to initialise the op amp on the RHS of the resistor and Zener diode?
    \draw (vp) -- ++(2,0) node[op amp, yscale=-1, anchor=+] (opamp) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although is better to use

```latex
\draw (vp) -- ++(2,0) node[op amp, noinv input up, anchor=+] (opamp) {};
```

instead of `yscale=-1`, for reasons explained [in the manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.2.2) around page 19 (as for the current version):

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rmano! Thanks for the quick comment, I was just about to post my own solution because I realised I could use anchor in the node itself haha.

Comment: Well, I added "pro bono" the info for `noinv input up` ;-) that will be useful in the future... you'll see!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about switching the inputs also